# Type 'false' is not assignable to type '((status: number) => boolean) | undefined' TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, axios

I'm using TypeScript and Axios to make a module, but I receive this error when I pass the AxiosRequestConfig:

`Type 'false' is not assignable to type '((status: number) => boolean) | undefined'.ts(2322)`

Code:

```js
const UIR = (await axios.get(`https://users.roblox.com/v1/users/${this.userId}`, { validateStatus: false })).data;
const USR = (await axios.get(`https://users.roblox.com/v1/users/${this.userId}/status`, { validateStatus: false })).data;
```

Please help me, thanks. I'll try to answer any question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript says that you cannot pass `false` there. You can either pass a `function` that returns `boolean` or `undefined`.

[Axios README.md](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/README.md#request-config) says:

> `validateStatus` defines whether to resolve or reject the promise for a given HTTP response status code. If `validateStatus` returns `true` (or is set to `null` or `undefined`), the promise will be resolved; otherwise, the promise will be rejected.

So, if you want validation to always pass, just pass a function that returns `true` or undefined:

```
const UIR = (await axios.get(url, { validateStatus: () => true })).data;
/// Or
const UIR = (await axios.get(url, { validateStatus: undefined })).data;
```

---

Actually, [from the source code](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/885ada6d9b87801a57fe1d19f57304c315703079/lib/core/settle.js#L13-L16) you can see that passing `false` will work. But I strongly recommend going with what the docs say.

Answer (score 0):

It's expecting the type to be a function that returns a boolean.

You simple need to change this:

```
{ validateStatus: false }
```

To this:

```
{ validateStatus: () => false }
```